# how to change the button colour and background colour in swift

Tags: swift, uibutton

so I want change the colour of my text and border when the button is tapped and change it back when not selected

here is my code

```
@objc func button_Select(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let button = sender

    if button.isSelected == true {


        button.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        button.layer.borderWidth = 1
        button.layer.borderColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9424466491, green: 0.6981263757, blue: 0.6917206645, alpha: 1)
        button.titleLabel?.textColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9424466491, green: 0.6981263757, blue: 0.6917206645, alpha: 1)
        button.isSelected = false

    } else {


        button.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        button.layer.borderWidth = 1
        button.layer.borderColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.6666666667, green: 0.6666666667, blue: 0.6666666667, alpha: 1)
        button.titleLabel?.textColor=#colorLiteral(red: 0.6666666667, green: 0.6666666667, blue: 0.6666666667, alpha: 1)

        button.isSelected = true
    }
}
```

but the result is when the button is selected the colour not changing into pink and when the button isn't selected the button text background change into grey colour not white/clear colour

Comment: use bool value.

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning tag to button and update tag value as 1 or 0, and apply condition based on tags as if tag equals 1 then set background color

Answer (score 0):

```
Follow this below steps -

1.Choose UITextField from the object library

2.Drag to your storyboard

3.Choose border style as none.

4.Create a Swift file and add this below extension -

extension UIView {

   @IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat {

    get {

        return layer.cornerRadius

    }

    set {

        layer.cornerRadius = newValue

        layer.masksToBounds = newValue > 0

    }

}

   @IBInspectable var borderWidth: CGFloat {

    get {

        return layer.borderWidth

    }

    set {

        layer.borderWidth = newValue

    }

}

   @IBInspectable var borderColor: UIColor? {

    get {

        return UIColor(cgColor: layer.borderColor!)

    }

    set {

        layer.borderColor = newValue?.cgColor

    }

  }

}



extension UIButton {

  func roundedButton(){

    let maskPAth1 = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds,

                                 byRoundingCorners: [.topLeft , .topRight],

                                 cornerRadii:CGSize(width:8.0, height:8.0))

    let maskLayer1 = CAShapeLayer()

    maskLayer1.frame = self.bounds

    maskLayer1.path = maskPAth1.cgPath

    self.layer.mask = maskLayer1

  }

}

extension UITextField {

   func setLeftPaddingPoints(_ amount:CGFloat){

    let paddingView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: amount, height: self.frame.size.height))

    self.leftView = paddingView

    self.leftViewMode = .always
}

  func setRightPaddingPoints(_ amount:CGFloat) {
    let paddingView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: amount, height: self.frame.size.height))
    self.rightView = paddingView
    self.rightViewMode = .always
  }
}

extension UITextField {

    @IBInspectable var maxLength: Int {
    get {
        if let length = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &kAssociationKeyMaxLength) as? Int {
            return length
        } else {
            return Int.max
        }
    }
    set {
        objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &kAssociationKeyMaxLength, newValue, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN)
        addTarget(self, action: #selector(checkMaxLength), for: .editingChanged)
    }
}

@objc func checkMaxLength(textField: UITextField) {
    guard let prospectiveText = self.text,
        prospectiveText.count > maxLength
        else {
            return
    }

    let selection = selectedTextRange

    let indexEndOfText = prospectiveText.index(prospectiveText.startIndex, offsetBy: maxLength)
    let substring = prospectiveText[..<indexEndOfText]
    text = String(substring)

    selectedTextRange = selection
   }
}
5.Now you can access this extensions either from storyboard or from code to change the values and see the effects.

6.You can change the corner radius, border width, border colour for UITextField.
Hope this method also helps
```

Answer (score 0):

use bool Value for check

```
// declare var
var checkBool = Bool()

 // In viewDidLoad
 checkBool = true

// On Button Action
@objc func button_Select(_ sender: UIButton) {
   if checkBool == true{
        button.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        button.layer.borderWidth = 1
        button.layer.borderColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9424466491, green: 0.6981263757, blue: 0.6917206645, alpha: 1)
        button.setTitleColor(#colorLiteral(red: 0.9424466491, green: 0.6981263757, blue: 0.6917206645, alpha: 1), for: .normal)
      //  button.setTitleColor(.red, for: .normal)

      checkBool = false
   }else{
        button.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        button.layer.borderWidth = 1
        button.layer.borderColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.6666666667, green: 0.6666666667, blue: 0.6666666667, alpha: 1)
        button.titleLabel?.textColor=#colorLiteral(red: 0.6666666667, green: 0.6666666667, blue: 0.6666666667, alpha: 1)

      checkBool = true
   }
}
```

hope it works for you

Comment: button.titleLabel?.textColor - this will not change the text color

Comment: button.setTitleColor(.red, for: .normal) ...(tested)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code...it may help you

```
 @objc func button_Select(_ sender: UIButton) {
    sender.tintColor = UIColor.clear
    if sender.isSelected == true {
        sender.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
        sender.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        sender.layer.borderWidth = 1
        sender.layer.borderColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9424466491, green: 0.6981263757, blue: 0.6917206645, alpha: 1)
        sender.setTitleColor(#colorLiteral(red: 0.9424466491, green: 0.6981263757, blue: 0.6917206645, alpha: 1), for: .normal)
        sender.isSelected = false

    } else {

        sender.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
        sender.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        sender.layer.borderWidth = 1
        sender.layer.borderColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.6666666667, green: 0.6666666667, blue: 0.6666666667, alpha: 1)
        sender.setTitleColor(#colorLiteral(red: 0.6666666667, green: 0.6666666667, blue: 0.6666666667, alpha: 1), for: .normal)
        sender.isSelected = true
    }
}
```